# jquery droppable add css after drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery droppable to add divs inside a larger div.  I am working on building a layout page.

see fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcc6/)

What I am trying to do is when the newRow or panel is dropped, add some css to it? i.e. make it draggable, change its color and so on...how can i do that?

i have tried.

```
  $('#panel').append("<div id='"+id+i+" class='subPanel draggable'>"+id+"</div>").addClass('subPanel draggable');
```

but that adds the css to the #panel div...

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot to close the single quote:

```
$('#panel').append("<div id='"+id+i+"' class='subPanel draggable'>"+id+"</div>");
```

[See result](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcc6/1/)

Comment: nice thanks. now it may be an unrelated problem, but that new div is not draggable.